# Spring Data Mongodb @Query with pagination

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Is there any way to write some query to mongo with *@Query* annotation and add paginaiton right into it. I have a method in repository

```
@Query("{'customer._id' : ?0 }")
List<Order> findOrderByCustomerName(String customerName);
```

and i want it to looks smth like this

```
@Query("{'customer._id' : ?0 }.skip{(?1 - 1) * ?2}.limit(?2)")
List<Order> findOrderByCustomerName(String customerName, int page, int size);
```

Is there any way to to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Pageable` as a parameter.

```java
@Query("{'customer._id' : ?0 }")
List<Order> findOrderByCustomerName(String customerName, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working.